# How to order Tasks from a Pool of Tasks to minimize time costs?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am trying to solve a problem where I am currently stuck an apreciate any help/hints/tips how to continue.

First I will explain you the problem and how I tried to tackle it.

**Basic Problem:**
There is a pool of tasks which need to be completed (about 50 Tasks are in the pool).
To change from one task to a new one there are costs (time).
There is a nxn-Matrix(ChangeCostMatrix) which shows the costs to shift every task.
The costs are asymmetric ( Costs from T1 to T5 = 5 and Costs from T5 to T1 = 2).

According to my understanding this is the (Asymmetrical) Traveling Salesman Problem which is well described in the literature.
Now I describe the Problem as Advanced Problem where I don't have any Idea how to solve it.

**Advanced Problem:**
Plan the next 50 hours (about 20 tasks can be settled) with tasks so that the costs are minimized.
That means take 20 tasks out of the 50 and minimize the costs and therefore solve as much tasks as possible. Each task takes some time to finish. This time is stored in a TaskDurationMatrix.

Each task in the pool has a date or time left until when it needs to be completed. In most cases this will result in lets say 10 tasks that need to be solved within the next 50 hours.
There will be a starting task given from where to start the optimal tour.

Summarized I try to solve the following task:
***Plan the next 50 hours with tasks, starting from a start task, where all tasks that need to be solved are solved and additional task are taken so that the time costs are minimal.***

Input:

- TaskPool n = 50
- StartingTask i.e. T4
- TimePeriod i.e. 50 h
- TaskDurationMatrix(1 x n): T4: 1h, T5: 1.5h ...
- AsymmetricChangeCostMatrix(n x n): T1 - T3: 3h, T3 -T1 2h

Output:

- Task Order for Time Period: StartikgTask -> T15 -> T11 -> T7 -> T23 -> T14 -> T18...

Obviously this is an optimization task.
Does anyone know how I can tackle that kind of task and just give me a basic where I can start or what area I need to get into?

Comment: confused a bit about how you would set up an objective function here.  What are the elements?  If you have roughly 10 required tasks, and time to do roughly 20 in a 50 hour period and you are trying to minimize time...why would you do more than 10 tasks?

Comment: Yes you understood it right but the goal is to take in as many as possible from the pool and do the required tasks as well. And for shifting from one taskt to antoher there are different time costs. The goal is to minimize the total time between the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [biased random-key genetic algorithm](http://mauricio.resende.info/talks/2012-09-CLAIO2012-brkga-tutorial-both-days.pdf) (BRKGA). BRKGA is a generic framework for constructing genetic optimization algorithms. The one non-generic bit is the decoder, which turns a chromosome consisting of several real numbers between 0 and 1 into a solution to the problem. In this particular case, you could specify that the chromosomes have one number per task, and interpret a chromosome as a sequence of tasks by selecting (1) the required tasks (2) the bottom k other tasks and sorting the tasks with a comparator that compares the corresponding alleles.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Okay i went trough the slides and I think i got the basic idea. But honestly I don't even know where to start now. The decoder is problem dependent in my understanding. And do I set the decoder up with all the informations i have as input?

Comment: @HumanAreKind The decoder needs to turn a vector with real entries in [0, 1] into a solution. If we have five tasks T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, of which T1 and T2 are mandatory, then we start by sorting them by vector entry. For example, if the vector is [0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1], then the order is T5 (0.1), T3 (0.2), T4 (0.3), T1 (0.4), T2 (0.7). We use the problem info to evaluate how long the set of tasks in that order take, then as long as that's too much time, we drop the last non-mandatory task (T4, then T3, then T5). Then report the objective for what's left.